# Is it possible to retrieve .env variables without godotenv.Load(".env")?

Tags: go, environment-variables

One of my colleagues has no need to use `godotenv.Load(".env")` to load credentials/webhooks etc. I think this has something to do with his launch.Json settings but I'm not sure. He's not available today so this is why I'm not asking him directly. Any suggestions on how to avoid the need for godotenv.(".env"), but still have an .env file from which the application gets its env variables? My launch.Json:

```
 "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch file",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "${file}",
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
        },
```

Tried to retrieve .env variables without using `godotenv.Load()`. Did not work.

Comment: Environment variables are read e.g via os.Getenv. A file `.env` file are not "environment variables" (but an abomination).

Comment: I am using os.Getenv() as well. But I'm wondering if it is possible to use it without using godotenv.Load(".env") beforehand. I still wish to use a .env instead of actual environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

try this

Add this function to bashrc or zshrc

```
    dotenv() {
        set -o allexport
        [[ -f .env ]] && source .env
        set +o allexport
    }
```

Reload

Then everytime you are in folder with .env inside, write `dotenv`

All content of file will be loaded

Enjoy !

Answer (score -1):

@Michielvdglind it is impossible to access the `.env` variable without loading a file into the environment using the `godotenv` package.

If you don't want to use a particular `godotenv` package you can use an alternative that:

1. viper : https://github.com/spf13/viper
2. env : https://github.com/caarlos0/env

Thanks, I hope this will help you to clear your doubt.

Comment: question  has no valid reason